# Get realtime data change update when data changes on Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written this code to fetch the data. But I want to fetch updates without restarting the activity as data changes in real-time in the database.

I want to show data dynamically:

```
FirebaseDB.batch.child(batch).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Update recyclerview here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get data in real-time, you should use a real-time listener. To solve this, please change your code to:

```
FirebaseDB.batch.child(batch).addValueValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Update recyclerview here
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    });
```

See, I have used Query's [addValueEventListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)):

> Add a listener for changes in the data at this location.

instead of [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)) which:

> Add a listener for a **single** change in the data at this location.

Comment: I read whole documentation but didn't tried ValueEventListener bcz I thaught SingleValueEventListener will listen every single value changes, Thats my bad :(

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong listener. According to [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) this listener will be triggered only once.

You need to use simple `ValueEventListener` as stated in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

Comment: I read whole documentation but didn't tried ValueEventListener bcz I thaught SingleValueEventListener will listen every single value changes, Thats my bad :(